# Proving $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(\ln n)^a}{n^b} = 0$ for all $a,b>0$

Tags: limits

How can I prove this:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(\ln n)^a}{n^b} = 0 \quad \forall\, a,b > 0$$

Any ideas or tips? I tried to use L'Hôpital's rule but that led into nothing.

Comment: This question must be asked at least one time here...

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write that

$$\frac{(\ln(n))^a}{n^b} = \left( \frac{\ln(n)}{n^{\frac{b}{a}}} \right)^a$$

Then you want to calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n^c}$ for $c>0$ (here Hospital's rule works well). And you conclude by continuity of $x\mapsto x^a$

Comment: You don't need continuity, just a strictly increasing transformation. See my answer.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are doing here...so you try to say that:
lim(x^a) = lim(x)^a?

Comment: Thanks, now I understand...this did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take the $1/a$th root of both top and bottom. That is a strictly increasing transformation so if the limit is $\infty$ then the original limit is $\infty$ as well. Now you can use L'Hopital and get something.

The new limit you will get is $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^{b-a}}$ which you can evaluate.

Comment: But what if b = 3 and a = 4? Then the limit is not 0...