# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{xe^x}{e^{x^2}}$.

Tags: limits

Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{xe^x}{e^{x^2}}.$$
I tried the L’Hopital’s rule but got nothing. Any help would be great!

Comment: Try L'hopital's on $$\dfrac{x}{e^{x^2-x}}$$

Comment: You could have posted this as an answer @rsadhvika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${{xe^x}\over{e^{x^2}}}$

$={x\over{e^{x^2-x}}}$

Hospital ${1\over{(2x-1)e^{x^2-x}}}$ the limit is zero

Answer (score 3):

Let $x>2$:

Note: $e^{x^2} > e^{2x}$, since $x^2>2x$.

$0 < \dfrac{xe^x}{e^{x^2}} < \dfrac{x}{e^x} $;

Take the limit.

Comment: I believe your method is that of the application of Squeeze Theorem, right?

Comment: Nzewi  Ernest Kenechukwu.Yes. Limit of LHS =0, limit of RHS = 0 , hence the limit in "the middle" =0; OK?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that
$$\frac{xe^x}{e^{x^2}}=\exp(-x^2+x+\ln(x))=\exp\left(-x^2\left(1-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2}\right)\right).$$
Then recall [Proving $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(\ln n)^a}{n^b} = 0$ for all $a,b>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474874/proving-lim-n-to-infty-frac-ln-nanb-0-for-all-a-b0?rq=1)